# How to make a collapsible or foldable table in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hi I want to present some data with group of people using rmarkdown

some table is large, say 100+ lines, and not all the people want to view so much detail, they may only need to check first 20 lines of the table

So is there a way to show at the beginning 20 rows of the table, but if they want they can unfold the table to see the rest part of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`datatable`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) from `DT` package.

For example:

```
DT::datatable(mtcars, options = list(pageLength = 20))
```

Shows only first 20 lines. And to show more lines you can change `Select N entries`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: That solves my question, and another benefit is DT package has other good use

Comment: @cloudscomputes happy to help :-)